# How to make Vue raise an error warning on non-existing key in v-for?

Tags: vue.js

I've rendered a list of objects in Vue component using v-for directive and by mistake passed non-existing prop as a key. However, Vue didn't throw any error or not even raised a warning. Question is how to make Vue throw an error on such case?

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-nash-qvwxy8?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0):

Try using Vue Devtools:

- Firefox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vue-js-devtools/
- Chromium - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Comment: and how is it going to help?